# Proper way to set file variables in an org-file

Tags: org-mode, doom, file-local-variables

I'm using doom-emacs with Emacs 28. I'm trying to set a file variable in org-mode, and I've seen numerous posts with how to do it, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
#+TITLE: Test


#+TITLE: Test
#+AUTHOR: Me


* Local variables
# local variables:
# eval: (auto-fill-mode 0)
#  eval: (poly-org-mode 0)
# org-html-xml-declaration: '(("html" . "") ("php" . "")
# end:
```

After doing `M-x describe-variable`, `org-html-xml-declaration` still has its original value.

Why is this? Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Is there a definitive guide for how to set local variables like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in the value you give for `org-html-xml-declaration`. If you check the `*Messages*` buffer, you will probably find one that says “File local-variables error: (end-of-file)”. It is telling you that it was trying to parse the local variables when it encountered an `end-of-file` error. You forgot a closing parenthesis, so it kept looking for it until it got to the end of the file.