# How to set a variable on a single buffer?

Tags: org-mode, file-local-variables, buffer-local

To set functions on a local buffer I use the following technique:

```
* Local Variables :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# eval: (view-mode 1)
# eval: (visual-line-mode 0)
...
# End:
```

However, when I try to set `org-image-actual-width` variable the following way:

```
* Local Variables :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# eval: (org-image-actual-width 600)
# End:
```

I have an error. And when I do:

```
* Local Variables :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq org-image-actual-width 600)
# End:
```

The variable is not only applied to the current buffer, but to all buffers.

What would be the proper way to set a variable on a single buffer only?

EDIT:

I found both Tobias' and NickD's answers very useful.

Tobias answered to the general question: How to set a variable on a single buffer?"

NickD answered to the specific question: why `org-image-actual-width` isn't working as it should?

Comment: Not recommended (@Tobias's answer is the way to do it), but you can try `setq-local` instead of `setq`.

Comment: `setq-local` doesn't work either.

Comment: I meant in the `eval: (setq-local org-image-actual-width 600)` - that should set the buffer-local value to 600 but leave the global value alone. Why it doesn't affect the displayed image size is a separate (and much less clear) question.

Comment: Yes, I meant `eval: (setq-local org-image-actual-width 600)` doesn't work. And when I say doesn't work I mean, doesn't affect the displayed image. As I said, only `setq` affects the displayed image.

Comment: As for the value it seems to be set, since that is how I understand `Its value is 600 Original value was t Local in buffer index.org; global value is t`

Comment: Well, that's not what I see: the buffer-local value affects the image in my case, so the question is why it does not in your case. What version of Org mode are you running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to set file variables in an org-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70588/proper-way-to-set-file-variables-in-an-org-file). Also [this question] (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/47502). See tag `file-local-variables` for more.

Comment: Changing the question after an answer has been posted is always a bad idea: somebody has spent time and effort to answer your question as you originally stated it and then you pull the rug out from under them. I would recommend that you revert your question (and your accepted answer) to the way it was. Then you can ask a new question based on your improved understanding. Part of it is my fault: I should not have engaged in conversation (something which SE is not good for in general and something I have railed against in the past). My only excuse was that I wanted to understand. I apologize.

Comment: I don't master the rules of stackexchange. Though I fully agree with you when you mean that the time people spend answering the question shouldn't be wasted for nothing. I changed the title and edited the question because I received a message saying that it was a duplicate and that it would be deleted if I don't edit it.

Comment: I agree with the idea that the question should be reverted to its original form. But I'm against its consequences which would be deletion due to duplication...

Comment: Here is the mentioned duplicate : https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70588/proper-way-to-set-file-variables-in-an-org-file. I reverted the accepted answer as you recommended.

Comment: Thank you! The question might be closed as a duplicate but AFAIK, it would not be deleted. Marking questions as duplicates helps users: people who are searching might find a duplicate but are then referred to the original where they can find an answer. People who answer can save time and effort by pointing to the duplicate.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates

Comment: You might want to click on the `?` icon in the upper right and read a bit about the "rules" (they are guidelines rather than rules, but they should be heeded). Here is a summary of the above discussion: Do not change a question in a way that would invalidate an existing answer that answers the original question correctly - ever. Think of the confusion that would cause to a new user who stumbles on that question. Instead, accept the answer and ask a new question, possilby referring to the previous one for context.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, I reverted the question title and changed the edit. I hope it suits you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval:` is a special form in the *Local Variables* section that evaluates the given Elisp-form. That is not what you want.

The actual syntax for setting file local variables is:

`MAYBE_COMMENT VARIABLE_NAME: VALUE`

So you set `org-image-actual-width` file-locally in the following way:

```
* Local Variables :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# org-image-actual-width: 600
# End:
```

See the [man-page about file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

Comment: I tried `# org-image-actual-width: 600` already, but it doesn't affect the image size. Contrary to `# eval: (setq org-image-actual-width 600)`.

Comment: Worked fine here. Two things:  did you check the value of the variable in the buffer (`C-h v org-image-actual-width`)? and did you reapply the mode (`M-x normal-mode`) after you added the local variables section? Alternatively, did you save and kill the buffer and revisit the file? Local variables are only applied when the mode is applied.

Comment: `C-h v org-image-actual-width` says :`Its value is 600
Original value was t
Local in buffer index.org; global value is t`. But it is not displayed as 600. After adding the local variable, I deleted `.emacs` content, only leaving `(require 'org)` and the link to my `init.org`, then I restarted emacs.

Comment: I don't know what `M-x normal-mode` does, but applying it didn't change the display, even after closing and reopening the file multiple times.

Comment: Just to be complete, the image is displayed through a link (eg `[[./image.gif]]`), and my init contains the two following lines : `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)`  and `(setq-local org-image-actual-width '(1024))`.

Comment: What happens if you toggle inline images to off and then back on again? And `setq-local` is not going to work if it is in your init file: that will make it local to the wrong buffer.

Comment: Even with `$ emacs -q` and `# eval: (setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)`, 
`# org-image-actual-width: 600` doesn't work...

Comment: Please separate the concerns: you are mentioning `org-startup-with-inline-images` in your comments but not in your question. Let's figure out *first* the `org-image-actual-width` situation *without* confusing the issue with additional considerations.

Comment: It is because if I tried `$ emacs -q`, I had to locally toggle inline image, otherwise the image wouldn't have ben displayed. Besides, I have  GNU Emacs 28.2 installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139167/discussion-between-nickd-and-crocefisso).

Answer (score 2):

[Not an answer: just a summary and linearization of the comments, which are pretty confusing as they stand and mostly deal with a *different* problem.]

1. The way to set a local variable is as described in @Tobias' [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73598/14825) and that *IS* the answer to the question (which the OP has accepted).
2. The additional problem was that the OP wanted the buffer to start with inline images displayed but at the same time, he wanted the size of those displayed images to be controlled by the locally set `org-image-actual-width`. That is a *different* problem and that was what the OP was referring to, in most cases, when he stated that it "did not work" (that's one reason why "it did not work" is not a good description of *any* problem: you have to say exactly what did not work - in this case, the local setting of the variable *did* work: but it required some additional digging to figure out what did not).
3. The reason that part 2. above did not work is that the `org-mode` function (which is called automatically to set the major mode of the buffer when you first open the file) decides whether to display inline images (based on the global value of `org-startup-with-inline-images` or whether the keyword setting `#+STARTUP: inlineimages` is found in the file) and does so *before* the local file variables are looked at, so setting `org-image-actual-width` as a local file variable is not going to affect that initial display. Only after doing `M-x org-toggle-inline-images` twice (once to disable inline images and once to re-enable them) are the images redisplayed at the specified size.

A workaround for this sequencing problem is to augment the `Local Variables` section as follows:

```el
* Local Variables :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# org-image-actual-width: 600
# eval: (org-display-inline-images)
# End:
```

Apparently, the local variables are evaluated top-to-bottom, so we first set `org-image-actual-width` and then do the `eval` which calls the function `org-display-inline-images` to display the images, but now at the specified width. The OP confirmed in the chat that that worked for him.